# Buscar una serie de valores en registros consecutivos

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

necesito comparar en un dataframe el registro N contra el registro N+1 (solo de los valores de la columna idCliente).

Si estos dos valores son iguales entre sí, y no son iguales comparándolos con un listado de strings, añadimos el registro N a un dataframe nuevo.

Paso lo que he probado:

```
clienteEncontrado = ''

listaClientes = ['testing' ,'test']

dfDef = pd.DataFrame()

for i in df.index:
    if( i+1 > len(df)):
        break
    else:
        clienteEncontrado = df['idCliente'].iloc[i]
        if(clienteEncontrado != df['idCliente'].iloc[i+1] and df['idCliente'].iloc[i+1] in listaClientes):
            continue
        else:
            dfDef = dfDef.append(df.iloc[i])
```

Me salta el siguiente error:

`IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds`

No sé donde estoy cometiendo el fallo, ya que estoy teniendo en cuenta la siguiente fila. Cualquier aporte o solución diferente es bienvenida!

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Un saludo.

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega algunas filas de tu `dataframe` así como un ejemplo del resultado esperado.

Comment: i + 1 no debe ser mayor al largo del dataframe, debe ser mayor o igual. Recuerda que la cuenta empieza en 0.